# Лицензия готового блога

Tags: html, css, лицензирование

Предположим. Я нашел блог, код которого лежит в открытом доступе и я его могу скачать (и скачал), я взял стиль блога и сверстал (в учебных целях) по своему видению, после этого я сделал из этого тему на WordPress. Могу ли я её продать? И где можно о подобном прочитать?
P. S. да, выглядит как то так... но всё же интересно. Спасибо!

Comment: Основной закон дизайна: не пойман - не вор, особенно если вор в другой стране.

Answer (score 1):

В открытый доступ выложил автор дизайна и кода блога?
Если сам, то на каких условиях, а если нет - то скорей всего без разрешения

Если вы и автор в разных странах, то можно продавать, закон тут не очень силён, особенно для такой вещи как *дизайн блога*
Единственное автор может жаловаться на вас в магазины, в которых вы будете продавать
А так, пока вы не будете зарабатывать существенную сумму, вами никто и не заинтересуется.

Answer (score 0):

Если там, где вы скачали «блог» нет указаний на то, по какой лицензии он распространяется, и место это находится в открытом доступе (т.е. доступно любому желающему), то беспокоиться скорее всего не о чем.

Comment: Нет, 4-я часть ГК РФ требует либо явно размещённого разрешения в «блоге», либо заключения лицензионного соглашения. Иначе никак нельзя.

Comment: Я не в рф живу.